# How do you save user answers received from a textField on a tableView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield, userdefaults

I have made a little quiz where a tableView holds different questions and answers as labels and textFields.

[image: questions and answers on tableView]

If the correct answer is entered the tableView cell turns green,the textField Text is set, and the textfield becomes uneditable.

[image: correct answer cell]

My problem is that none of these settings save. I need it to remember if the question was answered correctly and change the cell accordingly. I know I can use Core Data or User Defaults to save things but i'm not sure how get the specific cells that were answered correctly to save.

My code below:

TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let questions = ["what is 3 + 5", "what is the meaning of life","what 
    is the number from the jim carrey movie"]
    let answers = ["8","42","23"]

    var textfieldColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.23, blue:0.42, 
    alpha:1.0)
    var textFieldText = ""
    var isTextFieldEditable = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return answers.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Answers", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.question.text = questions[indexPath.row]

        cell.backgroundColor = textfieldColor
        cell.answerOutlet.text = textFieldText
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = isTextFieldEditable

        cell.answerOutlet.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {

        print(answers.contains(textField.text!))
        if answers.contains(textField.text!)
        {
            textfieldColor = UIColor.green
            textFieldText = textField.text!
            isTextFieldEditable = false

            let rowNumber = answers.index(of: textField.text!)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber!, section: 0)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
        }
       return true
    }



}
```

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
    @IBAction func Answer(_ sender: UITextField)
    {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOutlet: UITextField!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: when you mean save, do you mean that the data persist even after app restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Boolean check that changes inside the function `textFieldShouldReturn` and store the value inside an array and save it, something like this:

```
correct[rowNumber!] = true
UserDefaults.standard.set(correct, forKey: "Correct")
```

Then, change the loading of the table in tableView using the array:

```
if correct[indexPath.row] == false {

        cell.backgroundColor = textfieldColor1
        cell.answerOutlet.text = textFieldText
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = isTextFieldEditable
        }

        if correct[indexPath.row] == true {

            cell.backgroundColor = textfieldColor2
            cell.answerOutlet.text = answers[indexPath.row]
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
```

and finally, check each time you load the view, inside viewDidLoad to see if there are any results stored in UserDefaults:

```
if let corretAnswers = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Correct") {
        correct = corretAnswers as! [Bool]
        }
```

Comment: Forgot to tell you; you need to initialize the "correct" array with repeating: false count: 3